# How to horizontally align title?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, beamerposter

I can't get this to work. I have this:

```
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{title}[center]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\title{My title is here....!} % Poster title
```

It's automatically aligned *left*! While I want it to align in the *middle*.

What am I doing wrong here?

**This is the template I am using:**

https://www.overleaf.com/15692924fftndxdzdqbs#/59666612/

Comment: Can you also give the rest of the code. Something is clearly pushing it to the left apparently.

Comment: @percusse thanks for your response. This is the exact template I am using: https://www.overleaf.com/15692924fftndxdzdqbs#/59666612/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template you uses the headline to display the title. Within its definition of the headline it uses `\raggedright`. You can redefine the headline with `\centering` instead.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage[scale=1.150]{beamerposter} 
\usetheme{MUWposter} 

\title{Titel des Posters, Schriftgröße variabel} % Poster title
\author{AutorInnen, Schriftgröße variabel} % Author(s)
\institute{Klinik, Medizinische Universität Wien, Schriftgröße variabel} % Institution(s)


\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
 \leavevmode
  \begin{columns}
   \begin{column}{0.04\linewidth}
   \end{column}
   \begin{column}{0.9\linewidth}
    \vskip12cm
%    \raggedright
        \centering
    \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{blueMUW}\Huge{\textbf{\inserttitle}}\\[1.5ex] \par}
    \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{blueMUW}\LARGE{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{blueMUW}\normalsize{\insertinstitute}}
    \vskip1cm
   \end{column}
   \begin{column}{0.05\linewidth}
   \end{column}
   %\vspace{1cm}
  \end{columns}
 %\vspace{0.5in}
 %\hspace{0.5in}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=35in,colsep=0.15cm]{cboxb}\end{beamercolorbox}
 %\vspace{0.1in}
 \vspace*{-0.1cm}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t] % The whole poster is enclosed in one beamer frame
test
\end{frame} % End of the enclosing frame

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Sam. Is there a quicker way to do this? It feels like I have to do a lot of refactoring while I just want to center the title....

Comment: @Siyah You could have a look at the `xpatch` package -  but I honestly think just redefining the headline is easier

Comment: @Siyah or use another template which does not misuse the headline to display the title :)

Comment: It works though, so I am happy with this. Thanks, Sam!